# Hide/Show div with @mediaquery

Tags: css, media-queries, multiple-columns

I have a 3 col slideshow and hide 2 col when the user views the site w mobile. This was working and I tried adding another col and then decided not to. Since then this is not working, and I can't seem to see why.

My code:

```
<div id="rightCol">
    <div class="slideshowR">
        <img src="../images/slideshow/kettle.jpg">
        <img src="../images/slideshow/zucchini-flower.jpg">
        <img src="../images/slideshow/truffle.jpg">
    </div>
</div>
```

CSS:

```css
.slideshowR {
    height: 370px;
    width: 250px;
    margin: auto;
}   

#leftCol {
    width: 205px;
    float: left;
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    display: none;
}

#centerCol {
    width: 150px;
    float: left;
    margin: 0;
    padding-left: 10px;
    display: none;
}

#rightCol {
    width: 250px;
    float: left;
    margin: 0;
    padding-left: 10px;
}

@media only screen and (min-width: 769px) {
    #leftCol {
        display: block !important;
    }

    #centerCol {
        display: block !important;
    }

    #rightCol {
    }
}
```

Comment: which col is supposed to be hidden when in mobile? and which col should be displayed on desktop? it's an easy thing to do if the directions are clear

Comment: When in desktop I show all 3 columns. In mobile I only want to show the right column

Comment: @user3317435 updated answer to show right instead of left under 739px in width

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would just do this

```
#leftCol {
    width: 205px;
    float: left;
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
}

#centerCol {
    width: 150px;
    float: left;
    margin: 0;
    padding-left: 10px;
}

#rightCol {
    width: 250px;
    float: left;
    margin: 0;
    padding-left: 10px;
}

/* hide center and left in mobile */
@media only screen and (max-width: 769px) {
    #leftCol, #centerCol {
        display: none;
    }
}
```

Comment: <div id="rightCol">
              <div class="slideshowR"><img src=
                    "kettle.jpg">
                    </div>
            </div>
            <div id="mobSlide">
            <div id="rightCol2">
              <div class="slideshowR"><img src=
                    "artichoke-lrg.jpg">
                    </div>
            </div></div>
        </div>

Comment: for mobile:

    #leftCol, #centerCol, #rightCol {
    display: none;
   }

for desktop: 
   #leftCol {
    display: block;
   }
   
   #centerCol {
    display: block;
   }
    #rightCol {
     display:block;
   }
    #rightCol2 {display: block;
   }
   #mobSlide { display:none;
  }